# Anyone using XMPP to implement Push Notifications on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, push, real-time

I'm looking for any reference projects or key learning from anyone who has implemented XMPP/Jabber to successfully send notifications to iOS devices (iPhone/iPad).

I'm considering using an XMPP server ([OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) specifically) to provide a single cross platform mobile push system. C2DM for android has a number of annoying requirements like users having Google accounts. This is what got me started looking at XMPP. I also need to support pushing to iOS devices. I know all about APNS, however I'm wondering if I could use the XMPP server for both Android and iOS platforms (and possibly more like Black Berry).

The things I feel might come up are:

1. iOS killing any persistent connection to the XMPP server. Will it
   auto reconnect?
2. iOS preventing access to certain ports or protocols.
   Anything to be aware of here?
3. Other gotchas one would only discover
   by trying this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the answer to your first question:

> when your app goes in background you (the client) close the connection
>   with the xmpp server. When your app comes back into foreground you
>   reopen the connection. If your server need to send messages to your
>   client, it must use push notifications. When the client receives the
>   notification *can* (it depends on the user action) go back to
>   foreground.

(source: [iOS Backgrounding & XMPPFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229723/ios-backgrounding-xmppframework))